# Have a 'and' and 'or' in a single if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried having both an `and` and `or` in a single `if` statement but it didn't seem to work properly. I tried having the `and` both in front of and after the or (so `if ... or ... and ...` and also `if ... and ... or ...`), neither seemed to work correctly.

```py
# entryIndex is an int that increases by one every time in a for loop
if entryIndex % 11 == 0 or entryIndex == 0 and entryValue == '':
    # This should check if entryIndex == 0 or it has a remainder of 0 AND if entryValue is equal to ''
    ...
else:
    ...
```

So I had to separate it into 2 checks

```py
if entryIndex % 11 == 0 or entryIndex == 0:
    if entryValue == '':
        ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Use parenthesis !

Comment: `if (entryIndex % 11 == 0) or (entryIndex == 0) and (entryValue == ''):` for example

Comment: Why it doesn't work: https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: You don't need `or entryIndex==0`. That is covered by `entryIndex % 11 == 0`. You can just use `if entryIndex % 11 == 0 and entryValue == '':`

Comment: OR has priority

Comment: @Andrew That will have the exact same behavior. In order to change precedence the parenthesis have to group conditions (that would overwise would not be evaluated "together").  `entryIndex % 11 == 0 or (entryIndex == 0 and entryValue == '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yves Daoust suggested, use parentheses:

```py
if entryValue == '' and (entryIndex % 11 == 0 or entryIndex == 0):
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```

should work.

By the way, in your particular case, this can be simplified to:

```py
if entryValue == '' and entryIndex % 11 == 0:
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```

since if `entryIndex` is equal to 0, `entryIndex` is also divisible by 11.

Comment: Yep, that'd be it